# Alternative to PaymentSheet in stripe Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm currently developing a payment flow in an Android app, and I'm using Stripe API. It seems like the only option for the UI is Stripe's PaymentSheet, however, my company already has a custom UI for the payment screen, so I was wondering if there's an alternative to Stripe's PaymentSheet. I don't want to customize the PaymentSheet either by tweaking the PaymentSheet.Configuration. Is there an API that achieves the same result as when pressing the "pay" button in the Stripe's PaymentSheet? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a Payment UI you can use the older [CardInputWidget](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/payments-core/com.stripe.android.view/-card-input-widget/index.html) in place of the Payment Sheet.

The general [Accept a Payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=custom) tutorial includes this option as a tab, though it defaults to the Payment Sheet UI.

The obvious major caveat is this approach will only allow you to collect Credit Card payments.  However, you can implement [Google Pay](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=android) directly using the Stripe Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I was also wondering if there's something equivalent to CardInputWidget for the AddressElement? We also have made the UI for the shipping address screen as well, and we're thinking about not using Stripe's AddressElement while also being able to save the shipping address on Stripe's dashboard when our users complete the payment.

Comment: In the Stripe Android SDK Docs (https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/payments-core/com.stripe.android.view/-shipping-info-widget/index.html) I was able to find a ShippingInfoWidget but the only docs I can find on collecting address info in Android use the Address Element (https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element/collect-addresses?platform=android)

Comment: thank you for the resources, I will take a look! I was looking into CardInputWidget in Stripe, and on the Stripe's guides it's using xml to implement the UI. Do you know how to use CardInputWidget in Jetpack Compose by chance? I tried to call CardInputWidget as a composable function directly, but the card input element doesn't seem to show up when I test it, and it didn't report any errors either.

Comment: I don't think that Stripe Android currently has a Compose version of the CardInputWidget.  It appears to be in the dev backlog though, according to this Github issue: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/4226

Comment: thank you! I'm currently also using [ShippingInfoWidget](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/payments-core/com.stripe.android.view/-shipping-info-widget/index.html) to collect shipping information as you pointed out. I was wondering if you happen to know if there's a function that listens for the text input events on that widget, like the [setCardValidCallback](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/payments-core/com.stripe.android.view/-card-input-widget/set-card-valid-callback.html) function of CardInputWidget?

Comment: I cannot find any function that behaves in a similar way in the SDK or any mention of it it the GitHub repo.  That may be worth creating a Github Issue for so Stripe has a record of the feature request.  Additionally if you could accept my answer it will help others with similar questions.